# TDD: What to test in code where is 800 and more possible outputs?

Tags: tdd

I have class that have properties IsMacro, Value, Visible, DataType and one method GetResolvedValue. I dont know what to test. I do some math and I figure out that there is over 800 possible outputs for that method.

```
enum DataTypeEnum:
  Bool,
  String,
  DateTime,
  Integer,
  LongInteger,
  Decimal,
  ...

class Macro
  property bool IsMacro;
  property string Value;
  property bool Visible;
  property DataTypeEnum DataType;

  function GetResolvedValue(Resolver) {
      string value = Value;

      if (IsMacro && Visilbe) {
        value = Resolver.resolve(value);
      }

      switch (DataType){
          case String:
              // returns value if is string e.g.: "text"
              // othervise returns empty string
          case Bool:
              // returns value if is bool string e.g.: "true"
              // othervise returns empty string
          case DateTime:
              // returns value if is DateTime string e.g.: "2/2/2010"
              // othervise returns empty string
          ...
      }        
  }
```

So it must always return string with value that is valid for associated datatype or empty string.

With this code there is a lot of combinations and I dont know how to test it. Shoud I test all posible solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen to your tests!
Even now, before even being written, your tests tell you that this method massively violates the SRP and needs to be refactored.
You should probably extract a whole hierarchy of classes from this one method.